# is there a way to check if the req.body is including just set of parameters

Tags: express-validator

I am using express-validator middleware to validate the request body object, assume I expect the body to be

```
{
"username":"",
"email":""
}
```

is there's a way to make sure that the body does not include other keys
e.g: if the body is

```
{
"username":"",
"email":"",
"otherKey":""
}
```

I want it to be rejected

Answer (score 1):

### Please let us know what you've done

First of all you need to share your work, that you've made so far, so that we don't solve your issue totally on our own, but point you in the right direction.

### Solution + explanation

Alright, here's some tricky solutions. I assume that you need to do these things at the same time:

1. validate 2 necessary parameters, `username` and `email`;
2. check whether no other keys are included in request body.

Using `body()` with no parameters allows you to validate the whole **body** object.

Here's some info about it: [Whole body validation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/whole-body-validation.html)

The code listed below is an example of API endpoint `POST /login` that does what you need. Please refer to the third validator in middlewares array (`body().custom(...)`).

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

router.post('/login', [
    body('username').isString().not().isEmpty(),
    body('email').isEmail(),
    body().custom(body => {
        const keys = ['username', 'email'];
        return Object.keys(body).every(key => keys.includes(key));
    }).withMessage('Some extra parameters are sent')
], (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) return res.status(422).send(errors.array({ onlyFirstError: true }))
    next();
}, (req, res) => {
    //some other stuff
    res.status(200).send("OK")
});
```

You can also substitute the third validator with this one:

```js
body().custom((body, { req }) => {
    const keys = ['username', 'email'];
    return Object.keys(req.body).every(key => keys.includes(key));
}).withMessage('Some extra parameters are sent')
```

The only difference is that in this case you use `req` object, which you can always get in all `custom()` validators. This feature is described here: [Custom validation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#customvalidator)

> Receives the value of the field being validated, as well as the express request, the location and the field path.

### Results

Here I would like to share some screenshots that display `/login` endpoint behaviour:

1. [No data was sent in request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlcQe.png);
2. [Request body is (also) filled with unwanted keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQqmX.png);
3. [Request body is filled correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjjo8.png).